# Guest domain access internet

Tags: windows-server-2012, guest

I'm using Server 2012 in our environment, there are 2 Windows 8 computers joined the domain. I enable the Guest domain account in AD. Guest logins is ok but they cannot open Internet Explorer to access internet. How do I give permission to Guest just for Internet and not for LAN file sharing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I've never seen a use case for the Guest account. There's nothing inherently wrong with having generic users* for your organisation, but I think you should be creating specific users, groups and policies for these.

*I'm assuming you have a particular use case for allowing members of the public to log in

Comment: yes that is the case, we have these 2 pc for the public use. What permissions do I need to config for this type of users for them to just use internet access? Thanks.